# How can I install a .deb package in Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, deb

I'm trying to install [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) and this is what I did:

1. I got my JDK and used `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` in
   the terminal to install it and that seemed to work.
2. I downloaded the BlueJ installer from this link which is for
   Linux: http://www.bluej.org/download/files/bluej-314.deb

Other than doing this, I have no idea how to get it to run.

Comment: Please see this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/40781/67132

Comment: Thanks man, but when I enter in: sudo dpkg -i bluej-314.deb it gives me an error: dpkg: error processing archive bluej-314.deb (--install): cannot access archive: no such file or directory

Comment: You wrote that you downloaded `bluej-314.deb`. You must give the file as a parameter to the `dpkg -i` command. ------ Either switch to your download directory: `cd ~/Downloads` and run the command or give the full path to the command: `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/bluej-314.deb`. ------ Check if `~/Downloads` is indeed your download directory and the file is there.

Comment: The package is definitely in Downloads. I entered sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/bluej-314.deb in the terminal and it did not give me an error. The thing is that I don't even know how to launch the program... I am really sorry for my confusion, thank you so much for the help

Comment: In Ubuntu you either press the Windows logo key (between Ctrl and Alt) or the top button on the launcher panel on the left edge of the screen. This opens "Dash". Then you start to type the name of the application to start. After selecting the correct application press enter.

Comment: I have looked into `bluej-314.deb` and surprisingly the program executable is called `bluej`. So as another option simply try to run `bluej` from a terminal.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Problem solved, now I can actually use my computer!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory in which you've downloaded BlueJ .deb file: (Assuming it's your Downloads folder)

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then do

```
dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Change `filename` with the name of your .deb file. If you still get an error saying no such file or directory, write `ls` and see if the .deb file is listed there.

Comment: I tried that and it said "requested operation requires superuser privilege"

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg -i mypackage.deb
```

or  if you want skip dependencies check

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i  mypackage.deb
```

sudo is used to acquire root privilegies